Preventive against / of?

Quinine acts as a preventive against malaria.


Quinine acts as a preventive of Malaria.

Which sentence is correct?

Only the first sentence is "correct"! Both prepositions (against, of) are fine, but malaria should not be capitalized.

Edit
Preventive as a noun is common in medicine and pharmacy.
As a noun, preventive works with against and of, and both constructions are about equally common.
preventive against Malaria
preventive of Malaria

Thanks, @Michael Harvey.  I've edited my first paragraph.

There is no single "correct" choice of preposition for the cited context. Most common is of, but against, for, to, and from (and probably other prepositions) all occur, and are all perfectly valid.
See this usage chart.
